# Ordenar filas de jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ordenar

estoy intentando ordenar las filas de una tabla de jQuery, he leído del método sort pero me gustaría saber si existe algún otro método de ordenación pues no precisamente quiero que lo ordene de mayor a menor, o viceversa.

Tengo un arreglo de productos en donde dice en que máquina y cuanto tiempo, me gustaría que ordenara las filas por máquina y por tiempo, es decir ordenar ascendentemente los productos en la máquina 1 con el menor tiempo hasta arriba. Y para la máquina dos que sea al revés, que ordene los productos descendentemente, pero todo lo quiero en un mismo array.

En pocas palabras mi intención es programar Algoritmo de Jonhson con dos máquinas pero no se como reorganizar y reordenar.

Mi TABLA:

```
  <div class="card-body">
                  <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Producto</th>
                      <th>Menor</th>
                      <th id="Machine">Pertenece a</th>
                      <th>Hora</th>


                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody name="listaElementos2" id="listaElementos2" >
                      
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

Mi función:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#analisis').click(function(){
        obtenerDatosTabla();
          
        
      });
      });

      
      function obtenerDatosTabla(){

        
      document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML = '';
  

      $('#example1 tr').map(function(){
        
      //metodo de palmer
      let maq1=$(this).find('#OSTHM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq2=$(this).find('#FTHM').eq(0).text();          
      let maq3=$(this).find('#DTHM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq4=$(this).find('#CFTHM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq5=$(this).find('#DLTHM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq6=$(this).find('#LBTHM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq7=$(this).find('#NTHM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq8=$(this).find('#RMTHM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq9=$(this).find('#E1THM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq10=$(this).find('#E2THM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq11=$(this).find('#LTHM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq12=$(this).find('#C2THM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq13=$(this).find('#C3THM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq14=$(this).find('#EKTHM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq15=$(this).find('#M1THM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq16=$(this).find('#M2THM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq17=$(this).find('#CA1THM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq18=$(this).find('#CA2THM').eq(0).text(); 
      let maq19=$(this).find('#EFTHM').eq(0).text(); 



      let nombre=$(this).find('#nombre').eq(0).text(); 
      let cantidad=$(this).find('#txt-cant').val();
        
      
  

      multi=(2*maq1);
      var F1=multi+parseFloat(maq2)+parseFloat(maq3)+parseFloat(maq4)+parseFloat(maq5)+parseFloat(maq6)+
      parseFloat(maq7)+parseFloat(maq8)+parseFloat(maq9)+parseFloat(maq10)+parseFloat(maq11)+parseFloat(maq12)+
      parseFloat(maq13)+parseFloat(maq14)+parseFloat(maq15)+parseFloat(maq16)+parseFloat(maq17)+parseFloat(maq18);
      multi2=(2*maq19);
      var F2=parseFloat(maq2)+parseFloat(maq3)+parseFloat(maq4)+parseFloat(maq5)+parseFloat(maq6)+
      parseFloat(maq7)+parseFloat(maq8)+parseFloat(maq9)+parseFloat(maq10)+parseFloat(maq11)+parseFloat(maq12)+
      parseFloat(maq13)+parseFloat(maq14)+parseFloat(maq15)+parseFloat(maq16)+parseFloat(maq17)+parseFloat(maq18)+multi2;
      

       var M1= "Máquina 1";
       var M2= "Máquina 2";
     
        if(F1<=F2){
         for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) { 
        document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML +=
       "<td id=nombre>"+nombre+"</td>"+
        "<td id=F1>"+ F1 + "</td>"+
        "<td id=M1>"+ M1 + "</td>"  
         //Llave de If
        }
      }else{
      if(F2<=F1){
        for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) { 
        document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML +=
       "<td id=nombre>"+nombre+"</td>"+
        "<td id=F2>"+ F2 + "</td>"+
        "<td id=M2>"+ M2 + "</td>"   
      //Llave de for
      }
      //Llave de If
      }
      //Llave de Else
    }

     
      });

      
      }
   
      </script>
```

Comment: Puedes ocupar la libreria de Lodash, esta libreria tiene algunas funciones muy especificas como la que buscas en tu funcion.

te dejare el enlace directo: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy

Comment: Muchas gracias, revisare la documentación